# Copy Certain DataGridViewRow To New DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I want to copy all rows where the BackgroundColor = Green to a new DataTable.  I have tried the below syntax, but I am getting an error of

> can not convert 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to 'System.Data.DataRow'

What would be the proper way to write this synatx?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvMain.Rows)
{
    if (dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
    {
        ApprovedDTable.ImportRow(dr);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
And this is the line of code that throws the error with the `dr` underlined

```
ApprovedDTable.ImportRow(dr);
```

Comment: you need to check if the `dr.Cells["0"].DefaultCellSyle.BackColor ==` would be my best guess guess .you need to check either row[0].Cells[ ]  etc.. google it if you are truly stuck

Comment: @MethodMan - I was trying to add the entire row where the Color is green to a new datatable.  Which is why I went the ImportRow method.  If I go the Cells["0"] route, wouldn't I have to add each cell on that row one by one to the new datatable?

Comment: yes I know but getting the selected row is your main goal.. once again .. I would use google and understand how you can get at each cell cell takes either Index or by Column name meaning .Cell[0] or Cell["route"] for example use the debugger too and you can evaluate dr when stepping thru the code setting breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this syntax will suit your needs

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvMain.Rows)
{
    if (row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Green)
    {
        object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
        {
            rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        ApprovedDTable.Rows.Add(rowData);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is populating the DataTable with the appropriate number of rows, however it is not filling in all the data.